# Почему при добавлении блока «тег далее» в гутенберге в кастомном типе записи дублируется содержание записи?

Tags: php, wordpress, gutenberg

подскажите пожалуйста как решить следующую задачу.
Создал свой кастомный тип записи под названием "Услуги". При выводе записи на главной странице сайта, когда использую блок гутенберга "тег далее" почему то дублируется содержимое записи. При выводе родных записей вордпреса такой ошибки нет. Скриншот ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот блока который использую
[image: Скриншот блока который использую]

Скриншот того как вывожу запись на главной
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно я чего то недоуказываю при создании своего типа записи?

```
add_action('init', 'femida_uslugi');
```

function femida_uslugi(){

```
register_post_type('uslugi', array(
    'labels'             => array(
    'name'               => 'Услуги', 
    'singular_name'      => 'Услуги', 
    'add_new'            => 'Добавить услугу'),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => false,
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-businessman',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'uslugi', 'with_front' => true ),
    'supports'           => array('editor', 'title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
    'show_in_rest'       => true,
) );
```

}

Доступ к сайту femida.example3.pp.ua
логин: wp-admin
пароль: 12345678
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

"Тег далее" работал не корректно потому что был внутри блока "колонка"